# how to add observer on a view that someone is not tapping on view

Tags: swift, uiview

```
  // 1.create UIView  
     *lazy var  handleVedioView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view    //returning view
      }()

 //adding observer to my view
     view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: <#T##String#>, options: .new, context:nil)

 *//executing closure block
```

Comment: You mean you want continues observer until someone is not tapping on view?

Comment: yes @jaydeep and am using timer but problem with timer if am clicking on slider which is on that view the view will disappear after timer's time no matter what i am doing on that view ..so i want an observer to observe that i am working on that view..if am working don't disappear otherwise disappear after some sec..